# Chrome extension install parameter

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

My team and I are developing chrome extension. We have this parameter called **Session ID** which is unique for every user and should be generated during extension installation process. This extension should override search settings of chrome. Since we need to pass this session id to server side, we figured it out that we can add parameter in query string in homepage and other URLs in manifest:

http://www.search.com/?gd=XXXX&ISID=YYYYYYYYY

I have found this page:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override#customizing

I have changed homepage in manifest file to:
`http://www.search.com/?gd=XXXX&ISID=__PARAM__`
Then wrote C# application that writes to registry.

I should also mention that extension is uploaded to chrome web store.
After running it and restarting chrome, extension was installed successfully but `__PARAM__` occurences were not replaced. Is this possible or documentation on provided link is outdated?

Answer (score 0):

> I should also mention that extension is uploaded to chrome web store.

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override#customizing) explicitly mentions:

> For **[external extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override#customizing)**, the search_provider, homepage and startup_pages URL values can be parametrized using a registry key.

So, basically, you can't use that for Web Store-distributed extensions; this is intended only for enterprise policy-based deployments.